# Change log level with String value in java

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying to take in a request with some String value("Info, Warning, etc.) in order to change my applications level of logging. Currently, I just have 10 consecutive if-else statements...

```
public static void setLevel(String level) throws IOException {
    level = level.toUpperCase();
    if (level.equals("ALL")) {
        log("Log level set to ALL");
        saveLevel("ALL");
        logLevel = Level.ALL;
    } else if (level.equals("CONFIG")) {
        log("Log level set to CONFIG");
        saveLevel("CONFIG");
        logLevel = Level.CONFIG;
    } else if (level.equals("FINE")) {
        log("Log level set to FINE");
        saveLevel("FINE");
        logLevel = Level.FINE;
```

and so on. Each block logs the change to my log file, saves the level back to a file so it can be read the next time the app starts up, and changes the actual log level. There must be a much more concise way to do this. I've tried to use the following code

```
public static void setLevel(String level) throws SecurityException, IOException {
    level = level.toUpperCase();
    String[] levels = {"ALL", "CONFIG", "FINE", "FINER", "FINEST", "INFO", "SEVERE", "WARNING", "OFF"};
    if(Arrays.asList(levels).contains(level)) {
        log("Log level set to " + level);
        saveLevel(level);
        logLevel = Level.level;
    }
}
```

I put all the possible levels into a String array. However, I don't know how it would be possible to set the log level from a String. The only way I see is to do a series of if-else blocks to explicitly state logLevel = Level.INFO for whatever level is entered. Doing something like

```
String info = "INFO";
logLevel = Level.info;
```

doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd use a Map with level as the key and lambdas as value.  More concise.  I'm not sure why you don't have this as externalized configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your second code segment there with `loglevel = Level.parse(level)`, I think that should do it.

[Java Docs on Level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html)

Alternatively, instead of a string input, why not have the method take a Level directly? You can do `Level.info.getName()` to get the name if you really need to store it as a string somewhere, and then use parse as above to get the level back from that string. Avoids the verification there since the only possibilities for input would be the proper levels.

Comment: The purpose here is to take in a post request from a specific user that contains some string value, so I'd have to convert it from a string anyway. But, so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For log4j2 version 2.4 or 2.4+
We can change log level with String value by using **Configurator** class as follows:

```
// choose any level
String level = "info";

// org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
Configurator.setLevel("com.example.Foo", Level.toLevel(level));

// You can also set the root logger:
Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.toLevel(level));
```